# Python selenium : How to do a loop to find an element and click() on it multiple time until not exist?

Tags: python, selenium, click, findelement

I have this code to find element (delete product from cart), in my case i have more then one element so i need a loop de delete the products from cart one by one, this is my code but it's not working : `while(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')): self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]').click()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you are trying to click on an array of elements (`self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]').click()`).
Possible solution would be to use `find_element_by_xpath` (without the 's') when clicking.

Or

You should be able to do it with:

```py
# get all remove item buttons
removeButtons = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')
# loop over each element and click on it
for removeButton in removeButtons:
  removeButton.click()
```

Comment: Thanks works fine now, just a question how to stop the loop if i have no element to click on it?

Comment: hmmm, if you are using `while(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]'))` then change it to `while(len(self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')) != 0)` this will make the loop stop if there are no more elements to click on. If you are using the for loop that I suggested it should stop automatically once all elements are clicked.

Comment: Not working its doesnt click on the button

Comment: can you show the updated code?

Comment: `teams = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')
        for i in teams:
            actionchains = ActionChains(self.driver)
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
                EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')))
            i.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]').click()`

Comment: It delete just the first one

Comment: The `i` variable already contains the WebElement of RemoveProductBtn_btn you don't have to find the element again. Try this: `teams = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')
for i in teams:
    actionchains = ActionChains(self.driver)
    WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable(i)
    )             
    i.click()`

Maybe I should change the answer so it's better formatted, let me know.

Comment: This works fine :
`teams = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')
        for i in teams:
            actionchains = ActionChains(self.driver)
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 60).until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@data-testid="RemoveProductBtn_btn"]')))
            i.click()`